# Why python list slice assignment eats memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

I'm fighting a memory leak in a Python project and spent much time on it already. I have deduced the problem to a small example. Now seems like I know the solution, but I can't understand *why*.

```
import random

def main():
    d = {}
    used_keys = []
    n = 0
    while True:
        # choose a key unique enough among used previously
        key = random.randint(0, 2 ** 60)
        d[key] = 1234 # the value doesn't matter
        used_keys.append(key)
        n += 1
        if n % 1000 == 0:
            # clean up every 1000 iterations
            print 'thousand'
            for key in used_keys:
                del d[key]
                used_keys[:] = []
                #used_keys = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The idea is that I store some values in the dict `d` and memorize used keys in a list to be able to clean the dict from time to time.

This variation of the program confidently eats memory never returning it back. If I use alternative method to „clear” `used_keys` that is commented in the example, all is fine: memory consumption stays at constant level.

Why?

Tested on CPython and many linuxes.

Comment: How do you know for sure it never returns it? It might just be that the OS never asks for it back.

Comment: Shouldn't clearing `used_keys` be outside of the `for key in used_keys` loop?

Comment: >The idea is that I store some values in the dict d and memorize used keys in a list to be able to clean the dict from time to time.
Why not use just `d.keys()`? It will be same list of keys.

Comment: @adamk See a comment to the accepted reply.
@Daniel and @gnibbler Its just a model, if it were stand-alone code, I wouldn't use such odd methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the reason - the current method does not delete the keys from the dict (only one, actually). This is because you clear the `used_keys` list during the loop, and the loop exits prematurely.

The 2nd (commented) method, however, does work as you assign a new value to `used_keys` so the loop finishes successfully.

See the difference between:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> for x in a:
...    print x
...    a=[]
...
1
2
3
```

and

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> for x in a:
...    print x
...    a[:] = []
...
1
>>>
```

Comment: Ah!! I'm stupid, stupid, stupid. I was so happy to reconstruct the memory leak in a small snippet… It is a sad mistake, of course. It doesn't represent my problem, I gonna continue hunting. But you're right with the answer on the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't something like this work?

```
from itertools import count
import uuid

def main():
    d = {}
    for n in count(1):
        # choose a key unique enough among used previously
        key = uuid.uuid1()
        d[key] = 1234 # the value doesn't matter
        if n % 1000 == 0:
            # clean up every 1000 iterations
            print 'thousand'
            d.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```